# How to call function from other file | Php

Tags: php, function

I want to call function from other php file

Here is my code | but its not working for me,

**Configuration file**

```
    <?php
class config {
public static function get($param) {
$config = array(

// language selection,
'language' => 'english',

// allow users to sign up (true/false)
'allow_signup' => true,
);

        /**
         *
         * End of configuration options
         *
        */

        }
    }
```

**Other File** I want to call a function in this file that If "allow-signup" is true it should show a button to signup

```
<?php
require_once "configuration.php";

$app = new gator();
?>

<?php if (config::get('allow_signup')):?>
<input class="nice radius secondary button" style="float:left;" type="Submit" value="Sign up"> 
<?php endif;?>
        ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: What is the problem with question...

Comment: Please read the linked docs, they cover that stuff in detail.

Comment: In `echo lang::get("Sign up")`, what is `lang`?

Comment: lang removed. Still nothing

Comment: How about `echo config::get("Sign up")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not returning a value in your get config

```
<?php
class config {
  $config = array(
       'language' => 'english',
       'allow_signup' => true,
    );

  public static function get($param) {
     return $config[$param];
  }
}
```